# Timezone issues in EKEventStore in Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm pulling events off of the calendar and in the simulator it correctly pulls the date and time but when deploying to a device the timezone is all messed up. For example:

```
// Grab all events for the next 5 days
NSPredicate predicate = store.PredicateForEvents(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),new EKCalendar[] {});
Events = store.EventsMatching(predicate);
foreach(EKEvent myevent in Events)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event date: " + myevent.StartDate.ToString());
}
```

This will produce `Event date: 2011-02-04 18:29:59 +0000` (PST) on the simulator but on the iphone will produce `Event date: 2011-02-04 02:29:59 +0000` which is also in PST.

I've searched everywhere for this and I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cast it to a DateTime first then ToLocalTime it will give you the date in current local time.

((DateTime)myevent.StartDate).ToLocalTime()